# JavaScript redirection error

Tags: javascript, php, redirect

I am trying to use JavaScript to redirect to a PHP page on my site, however, when I do it, nothing happens, apart from the alert boxes if I do not fill in the parameters. Is there something I am doing wrong?

```
document.getElementById("submit").onclick = check;
function check()
{
    if(document.getElementById("name").value == "")
    alert("The field 'Name' is required.");
    else if (document.getElementById("message").value == "")
    alert("The field 'Message' is required");
    else
    window.location.href = "scripts/main/contact.php?msg=" + document.getElementById("message").value;
}
```

Comment: Have you checked the console for error messages?

Comment: only one condition will pass, and it seems to be the one with the alert box

Comment: document.getElementById("submit").onclick = check(); isn't it?

Comment: Can you post your markup too?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why are you not just using POST and why are you requiring the 'name' field when you are not doing anything with it?

Comment: @putvande how would I use POST?

Comment: `<form action="scripts/main/contact.php" method="post"> ...`

Comment: @gypsyCoder, It can be used as OP wrote here also until it goes outside script tags.

Comment: Have you checked the console after running it. Make sure that you have copy and pasted `name`,`message` and `submit` ids from your code. I usually make this mistake..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your default form action takes place overriding your redirect. Return false from the handler to prevent it from taking place:

```
function check()
{
    if(document.getElementById("name").value == "")
      alert("The field 'Name' is required.");
    else if (document.getElementById("message").value == "")
      alert("The field 'Message' is required");
    else
      window.location.href = "scripts/main/contact.php?msg=" + document.getElementById("message").value;

    return false; // <------ here
}
```

Comment: What would be default action?

Comment: @Manoz Whatever is written in the action attribute of the form. If nothing is written (my guess), then the page is reloaded.